# Data Transformation in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have a data set

```
From | To | Val1 | Val2 | Val3
123 130 AB  DE  EF
131 140 WS  ED  RF
141 145 GT  HY  JU
```

and I want to print the following data set in PostgreSQL

```
ID | Val1 | Val2 | Val3
123 AB  DE  EF
124 AB  DE  EF
125 AB  DE  EF
126 AB  DE  EF
127 AB  DE  EF
128 AB  DE  EF
129 AB  DE  EF
130 AB  DE  EF
131 WS  ED  RF
132 WS  ED  RF
133 WS  ED  RF
134 WS  ED  RF
135 WS  ED  RF
136 WS  ED  RF
137 WS  ED  RF
138 WS  ED  RF
139 WS  ED  RF
140 WS  ED  RF
141 GT  HY  JU
142 GT  HY  JU
143 GT  HY  JU
144 GT  HY  JU
145 GT  HY  JU
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something using this

```
SELECT generate_series(1,10)
```

So without fully testing

```
SELECT generate_series(A.FROM, A.TO), Val1, Val2, Val3
FROM (SELECT * FROM your_data_table) A
```

Comment: Is there a way I can do this in MS Access too?